# Ajax-окна как страница сайта

Tags: ajax, php

Всем привет.

В процессе создания окон ajax наткнулся на проблему.

Создается отдельная страница, которая и попадает в окно ajax. На эту страницу можно перейти по адресу, что кране не нужно. Как запретить переходить на такие страницы напрямую? Я думаю, что нужно проверять - iframe окно ли это или нет, но как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: iframe не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к ajax

Comment: Ок, но как бороться в такой ситуации?

Comment: Уточните: у вас через Ajax погружается страница в модальное окно или iframe, а адрес на эту страницу берется из ссылки, по которой и кликают?

Comment: используется плагин для Jquery - colorBox. В функции указывается ссылка на страниц. А плагин подгружает в окно. Наверное iFrame

Comment: Собственно, сложность для вас состоит в том, что это плагин. Сами, я так подозреваю, вы не сможете его заточить под свои нужды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я там чуть обнюхал этот colorBox. В общем, кое-что можно придумать. [Сделал пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/hqF82/1/) очень примитивно и только для того, чтоб показать принцип работы. По клику на ссылку, вытаскиваем её ID. В примере я ID использовал, как некий маркер, а вы по нему можете вытаскивать ссылку из базы, например. Или изначально создать массив ссылок. В общем, тут уже на ваш вкус.

Answer (score 0):

Если юзер не знает о GET или POST то, через ссылку в аякс окно передавайте какой нибудь параметр 
Пример:

```
 $ajax = $_GET['ajax'];
    if ($ajax){
    //тут вы делаете то, что вам надо что бы потом загрузить в окно.
    }
    //А если страницу будут запрашивать напрямую то, собственно параметра ajax не будет и поэтому скроем страницу
    else (!$ajax){
    echo "У вас нет прав для просмотра данной страницы";
    }
```

Только вот лучше передавать все это через POST так как если пользователь увидит этот "ajax" то он просто его подставит и все, а через POST фигушки он что-то подставит.

Comment: О да, пользователь, конечно, добросовестно проигнорирует параметр типа `ajax=1` в url'e и будет недоумевать почему у него пустая страница. Да вы "гений"

Comment: Да я имел ввиду, что бы @Nick все делал через аякс

Comment: Тем более у него была метка "ajax" вот я ему и дал хоть корявый, но пример.